# Windows' default certificate store for intermediate vs trusted root certificates - my self signed root CA cert goes to 'intermediate' by default?

Tags: windows, certificates, certificate-authority

Is it possible to create self-signed root CA certificate that Windows will import to Trusted Root by default instead of Intemediate certificate store ? Obviously, it won't do it without the big giant nag window asking if you're really sure - but it would be nice to not have to go the extra step of specifying which certificate store it goes in.

Currently, both our root CA and intermediate certificates by default (if you just right click > install) go into the intermediate certificate store. If I tell it to install to trusted root store for the root cert, then everything works as expected (trust chain etc). However, ideally we shouldn't have to set this and instead have it assume it should go there (it would still display the are-you-sure dialog). Is this possible?

We have built (and are still fine tuning) a CA using phpseclib. As an example here is a root CA I generated (with sanitized details):

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Are we doing something wrong, setting or not setting an extension? Perhaps it needs to be in pfx or other format instead of PEM? Or will Windows always default to intermediate, and nothing to be done about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows applies some not-really-documented heuristics to know where your certificate should go. Apparently, these heuristics have changed: when I import your certificate on a Windows XP system, it defaults to the root store (with the big warning), but when I try on a Windows 2008R2 system, it goes to the intermediate CA store.

One way to side-step the issue is that root CA are very sensitive objects, and should not be imported "automatically". A rogue root CA can be used to deal considerable damage on the victim and I am not sure a single popup is really enough as a protection measure. The popup is not even red and scary-looking; it is more like a boring wall of text:

[image: Warning popup for a new root CA]

It is like license agreements: who really reads them, honestly ?

Under these conditions, I cannot really blame Microsoft for directing *by default* certificate imports to an intermediate CA store.

---

Now for your specific question, if I were to hazard a guess about what makes some Windows versions consider your certificate as "probably not a root CA", I would point at the short lifetime. Root CA certificates usually last longer than one year. I suggest trying to make that certificate valid for 20 years or so. This may or may not solve your problem, but if it does, so much the better.

**Note:** a certificate which is both self-issued (subject DN and issuer DN are equal) and self-signed is not necessarily a root; as per [X.509](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280), a CA may emit such things if it wants to handle a smooth transition when trying to change some characteristic in its certificate. The [path validation algorithm](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-6.1) includes a lot of provisions for such self-issued *intermediate CA* certificates.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed analysis. I will try various lifetimes and see if that has any effect, and report back. The whole project was back-burnered for awhile do to the usual IT stuff, only just now had a chance to check if anyone had any insight.

Comment: Well, increasing the years hasn't worked thus far, have gone up to 25 year lifetime.

Comment: I tried saving out an unsigned cert (since what you said about being self signed not necessarily a root, made it sound like from phrasing that a root can also be unsigned?) but at least with phpseclib that didn't work at all (emitted zero length X509 output). So, I guess TL;DR: This can't be done, at least with phpseclib.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to control Windows certificate heuristics, but you can still make it a one-step operation.

You can distribute a script that does it. Note that **this must be run by an administrator since the machine's root store cannot be modified by unprivileged users**. Assuming the certificates are on a network share, you could use:

```
certutil -addstore Root \\path\to\rootcertificate.cer
certutil -addstore Intermediate \\path\to\intermediatecertificate.cer
```

Alternatively, I believe **a non-administrator can install the certificate just for himself with the "-user" option**, e.g.:

```
certutil -user -addstore Root \\path\to\certificatefile.cer
```

If you have a domain, **it is far easier to distribute certificates to the appropriate stores via Group Policy**. This makes it automatic upon joining the domain, so there is no action required on the client.